# putting 15 vct transformer in series to get 30 vct output

Tags: transformer

i have this 15 vct transformer. 
[image]

as you can see, it's 15v 0v 15v center tapped transformer.

I want to make these two transformer behave as a 30 vct transformer.
then, in this picture, is A 30V and B 0V(center tap) and C 30V, if you see this as a single transformer? and the current should be same as one of them.

Also the input says' 0v, 110v, 220v'. i have a standard 220v socket, then should i put one cable(two ends) on the 0v and the other on the 220v input?

those two transformers are completely identical.

Comment: Connect primaries in parallel on 0 to 0, 220 to 220. Please use standard English capitalisation to make your posts more readable, including 'V' for volt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i connect wires in a single transformer to get higher volts?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/can-i-connect-wires-in-a-single-transformer-to-get-higher-volts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primaries are wired in parallel and secondaries in series. No problem there at all but, there is a small chance that the secondaries are out of phase and the output voltage will be zero - just like when you have a battery compartment for two series connected batteries and you reverse one of those batteries.

Be prepared to swap over the secondary winding of one of the transformers to make it work but, chances are it'll be fine.